# Set color to background-image svg

Tags: svg

I'm using svg sprite for icons, which set each svg icon as a background image on the element. Now I can't set color for icons. I have tried by color, by fill from css, but it doesn't works. How can I set style to svg icon from sprite ?

Comment: You can't if you use background images. They basically make SVG work like raster images (only scalable).

Comment: Is there a way to set color to svg by fill attribute, then generate svg sprite ?

Comment: I'm using "grunt-iconizr" for svg sprite generation, you mean change the options ?

Comment: No I mean write a replacement for grunt-iconize that does exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.